# Tensorflow GPU memory allocation

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to train a custom object detection model using my GPU instead of CPU. I've followed all the instructions given in the following tutorial: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/

I've tested my software and everything is installed and working correctly.

Currently using:

- Windows 10
- NVIDEA Quadro P1000
- Tensorflow version 2.4.0
- CUDA 11.0
- CuDNN 8.0.4
- Pre-trained model = ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8
- Number of classes to detect = 8
- Batch size: 1

The problem however is that after training for a few seconds it stops using the GPU giving the following warning messages.

```
2020-12-29 15:01:15.444931: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:18.923079: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2020-12-29 15:01:18.928526: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.830691: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: Quadro P1000 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.5185GHz coreCount: 4 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 89.53GiB/s
2020-12-29 15:01:19.838069: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.849650: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.854098: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.861632: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.867525: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.879754: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.886521: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.891603: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.895368: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-12-29 15:01:19.900144: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-12-29 15:01:19.910485: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: Quadro P1000 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.5185GHz coreCount: 4 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 89.53GiB/s
2020-12-29 15:01:19.917796: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.922273: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.926687: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.930618: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.934399: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.938808: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.943155: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.947005: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:19.950826: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-12-29 15:01:20.491701: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-12-29 15:01:20.496963: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0
2020-12-29 15:01:20.500990: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
2020-12-29 15:01:20.504027: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2991 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Quadro P1000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-12-29 15:01:20.512219: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
I1229 15:01:20.515150  5872 mirrored_strategy.py:350] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
I1229 15:01:20.515150  5872 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I1229 15:01:20.515150  5872 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py:523: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W1229 15:01:20.530780  5872 deprecation.py:339] From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py:523: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['annotations/train.record']
I1229 15:01:20.546404  5872 dataset_builder.py:148] Reading unweighted datasets: ['annotations/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['annotations/train.record']
I1229 15:01:20.546404  5872 dataset_builder.py:77] Reading record datasets for input file: ['annotations/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I1229 15:01:20.546404  5872 dataset_builder.py:78] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W1229 15:01:20.546404  5872 dataset_builder.py:86] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:103: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W1229 15:01:20.546404  5872 deprecation.py:339] From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:103: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:222: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W1229 15:01:20.562029  5872 deprecation.py:339] From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:222: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W1229 15:01:25.685788  5872 deprecation.py:339] From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
W1229 15:01:27.908942  5872 deprecation.py:339] From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\inputs.py:281: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W1229 15:01:29.229117  5872 deprecation.py:339] From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\inputs.py:281: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
2020-12-29 15:01:31.781125: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:434: UserWarning: `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11. To update it, simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
  warnings.warn('`tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and '
2020-12-29 15:01:48.972736: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:49.258182: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:49.287771: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2020-12-29 15:01:49.822205: I tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:308] SubProcess ended with return code: 0

2020-12-29 15:01:49.866004: I tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:308] SubProcess ended with return code: 0

WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._groundtruth_lists
W1229 15:01:52.823682  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._groundtruth_lists
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor
W1229 15:01:52.823682  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._batched_prediction_tensor_names
W1229 15:01:52.823682  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._batched_prediction_tensor_names
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head
W1229 15:01:52.823682  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads
W1229 15:01:52.823682  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._sorted_head_names
W1229 15:01:52.823682  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._sorted_head_names
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers
W1229 15:01:52.823682  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads.class_predictions_with_background
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads.class_predictions_with_background
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.0
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.0
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.1
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.2
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.3
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.3
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.4
W1229 15:01:52.839355  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.4
W1229 15:01:53.076874  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.7.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.axis
W1229 15:01:53.076874  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.gamma
W1229 15:01:53.076874  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.beta
W1229 15:01:53.076874  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.moving_mean
W1229 15:01:53.076874  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.moving_variance
W1229 15:01:53.076874  5872 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4.10.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
W1229 15:01:53.076874  5872 util.py:169] A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.468799  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.468799  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.468799  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.468799  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.468799  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.468799  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.468799  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.484427  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.484427  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I1229 15:01:53.484427  5872 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:605: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
W1229 15:01:59.423827 15152 deprecation.py:537] From C:\Users\USER-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:605: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
2020-12-29 15:02:11.320699: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.73GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:11.351326: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.74GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:11.751709: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.08GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:11.784850: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.09GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:12.607912: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.14GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:12.644507: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.15GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:13.057969: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.05GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:13.092341: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.06GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:13.299573: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.04GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-12-29 15:02:13.331704: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:248] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.06GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

Furthermore, I'm not running any other programs on my device so it seems kind of weird that it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this error message for four different reasons, with different solutions:

#### 1. You're out of memory

Maybe your GPU memory is filled, when TensorFlow makes initialization and your computational graph ends up using all the memory of your physical device then this issue arises. The solution is to use allow `growth = True` in GPU option. If memory growth is enabled for a GPU, the runtime initialization will not allocate all memory on the device. Using the below code snippet after imports may solve your problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

#### 2. You have cache issues

I regularly work around this error by shutting down my python process, removing the ~/.nv directory (on linux, rm -rf ~/.nv), and restarting the Python process. I don't exactly know why this works. It's probably at least partly related to the second option:

#### 3. While using Keras, Keras layers(classes) were directly imported from keras instead of tensorflow.keras

Keras is included in TensorFlow 2.0 above. So

remove `import keras` and
replace `from keras.module.module import class` statement to --> from `tensorflow.keras.module.module import class`

For example
Replace
 `from keras.layers import Conv3D,ConvLSTM2D,Conv3DTranspose, Input`
with this:
`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D,ConvLSTM2D,Conv3DTranspose, Input`

#### 3. You have incompatible versions of CUDA, TensorFlow, NVIDIA drivers, etc.

If you've never had similar models working, you're not running out of VRAM, your imports are right as mentioned in step 3 and your cache is clean, I'd go back and set up CUDA + TensorFlow using the best available installation guide - I have had the most success with following the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu rather than those on the NVIDIA / CUDA site. Lambda Stack: https://lambdalabs.com/lambda-stack-deep-learning-software is also a good way to go.

Comment: I've tried all the options even re-installed CUDA 11.0 and CuDNN 8.0.4 but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Please check your GPU driver version, it must be 450 another solution would be please try to install cuda toolkit 10.1 along with cudnn 7

Comment: I've installed tensorflow 2.3 with CUDA 10.1 along with CUDDN 7.6.5 and I'm still gettting the same type of error "(1) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8,256,80,80] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc"

Comment: now the problem is allocating the memory for your tensor, I think you have a GPU with very low VRAM, what I would suggest you know is that either lower the size of your data types such as float32 or float16 instead of float64, other solution would be to lower the bath size.

Comment: The first solution worked for me. I was testing a PyTorch Model and Keras model in same notebook. While Keras was working after PyTorch, Pytorch was not working after Keras. Keras was allocating all the available memory to itself after defining the model